# Designing issue in highchart with drilldown chart

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I've facing designing issue in highchart drill down chart

Above issue is face when not including **subtitle** and **title** has blank("") in chart option

I don't want to include subtitle and title in chart option , so what should i do to resolved this

**Actual Result** :-

[image]

**Expected Result** :-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that by setting `marginTop` option:

```
chart: {
        marginTop: 50
    },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gz8w1kLb/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginTop